# why does this sed pattern not working in python loops?

Tags: python, regex, linux, python-2.7, sed

Currently i have a file with `displayName = "CLIENT-MASTER"` . I need to change the `"CLIENT-MASTER"` to some `"XXX"`. For this i have written a sed pattern which works perfectly fine when i execute `sed` on the console.But when i put the `sed` pattern in the python list and use it in for loop it is not working as it is expected.

`sed` pattern:

```
sed 's/displayName.*=.*\"CLIENT-MASTER/displayName = \"DUMMY/' CLIENT-MASTER.vmx > junk
```

This works perfectly fine and the result is like this

```
displayName = "CLIENT-MASTER"  > displayName = "DUMMY"
```

When i put this pattern in the list and print the list it is like this,
    `c_master = 'DUMMY'`

```
listElm = ['s/displayName.*=.*\"CLIENT.MASTER/displayName = \"{0}/g'.format(c_master)]
>>> listElm
['s/displayName.*=.*"CLIENT.MASTER/displayName = "DUMMY/g']
```

The back slash infront of DUMMY is missing.So when this pattern gets executed ,the result is this way,

```
displayName = "CLIENT-MASTER"  > displayName = DUMMY"
```

The double quotes is missing.I need that string to be replaced should be within double quotes.What am i missing here?

Comment: Where do you create `c_master`?

Comment: i am creating it under the same function. c_master = DUMMY

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code that creates `c_master`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the backslash then try escaping it :-

```
listElm = ['s/displayName.*=.*\\"CLIENT.MASTER/displayName = \\"{0}/g'.format(c_master)]
```